# Permission denied when trying to run .bin on Linux webserver

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I am trying to run a compiled C++ program on my webserver (Debian), but the terminal is outputting the following error message:

```
-bash: ./program.bin: Permission denied
```

The rights on `program.bin` are set to `-rwxr-xr-x`, which means that it should have the permission to be executed. I already tried running `/bin/bash program.bin`, but this is giving me this error:

```
ovInterface.bin: ovInterface.bin: cannot execute binary file
```

The hosting provider of the webserver probably has forbidden this, since there are a lot of websites/accounts hosted on my webserver. If that's the case, is it possible to bypass this restriction? I was able to run `.php` files in the background of the webserver, which had an infinite for loop and handled socket connections etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

EDIT:

I found out that the `cannot execute binary file` error from `/bin/bash program.bin` means that the compiled program is not built for the system architecture. `program.bin` was compiled on another machine (however both are 64-bit).

If it is possible to run the `.bin` file using `/bin/bash`: How do I compile C++ code to executables without access to `gcc`, `g++`, `make` and `apt-get`? Can I upload a compiler executable to my webserver and compile the C++ source then?

Comment: `/bin/bash` is an interpreter, it only interprets bash, not random compiled binaries. `cannot execute binary file` means it's binary, not a bash script; I don't see why it has anything to do with architecture, on face value. If `./program.bin` says `cannot execute binary file` I would believe it's an architecture problem, but that's not the case.

Comment: As for uploading a compiler executable: yes, I believe you can do that, as long as you cross-compiled for the destination architecture.

Comment: Don't ask me. GCC's [compilation and installation instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/) are pretty extensive.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Oh by the way I haven't been dealing with compilers for a long while, so it is entirely possible that I'm mistaken. Please excuse me if I turned out to be wrong.

Comment: The `file` command can tell you exactly what kind of file `program.bin` is, which would help you evaluate the proposition that it does not match the system architecture.

Comment: Wrong architecture is not the only possible problem -- another plausible one is that the program depends on a shared library that is unavailable on the system where you are trying to run it.  The `ldd` command can tell you what shared libraries `program.bin` requires, and whether they are available.

Comment: Yet another plausible problem is that the server is enforcing mandatory access controls (SELinux), and the local security policy prevents you running it.  This is separate from and independent of the file mode bits.  In that case, you would need to talk to whoever administers the machine to determine how (and whether) to proceed.